# Интеграция JWPlayer в TinyMCE

Tags: javascript, tinymce

Привет всем! Кто-нибудь работал с TinyMCE, а с JWPlayer? Так как это тема как раз для тех, кто имел дело с этими двумя javascript инструментами! Итак начнем, есть видео плеер JWPlayer и чтобы поставить видео на страницу, нужно вставить вот такой код:

```
<div id="mediaplayer">Видео будет здесь</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jwplayer.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jwplayer("mediaplayer").setup({
        flashplayer: "player.swf",
        file: "video.mp4",
        image: "preview.jpg"
    });
</script>
```

И я тут подумал, не буду же я клиенту говорить, чтобы поставить видео, вам надо вставить вот такой вот код на страницу )) то есть в TinyMCE [HTML]. Нужно сделать так в TinyMCE, чтобы была кнопка  добавить видео и при нажатии на него выходит модальное окно самого редактора TinyMCE и в нем будет поле URL к видео. И при добавлении видео TinyMCE (редактор) создаст такой вот скрипт и вставит в HTML (в редактор). Если кто знает реализацию, подскажите, как сделать такое?

Answer (score 1):

Напишите простой плагин:

```
(function (tiny) {

    tiny.PluginManager.add("jwplayer", function (editor, url) {
        function showDialog() {
            editor.windowManager.open({
                title: 'jwplayer video',
                file: url + "/jwplayer.html",
                width: 800,
                height: 530,
                inline: 1,
                resizable: true,
                maximizable: true
            });
        }

        editor.addButton("jwplayer", {
            icon: true,
            image: url + "/img/jwplayer.gif",
            tooltip:  'тултип кнопки',
            onclick: showDialog,
            onPostRender: function () {
                var self = this;
                editor.on("NodeChange", function (e) {
                    self.active(e.element.nodeName === "IMG");
                });
            }
        });
    });
}(tinymce));
```

Полный пример: https://github.com/gtraxx/tinymce-plugin-youtube

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно посмотреть примеры создания плагинов на сайте **TinyMCE**.